# Find $\int_ \! \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-x-1}} \, \mathrm{d}x. $

Tags: calculus

> Find $$\int_ \! \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-x-1}} \, \mathrm{d}x. $$

I just did it:

$$ \int \frac 1{\sqrt{(x-a)^2 - b^2}} \, dx = \ln \left(x-a + \sqrt{(x-a)^2-b^2 } \right)  + C$$

Comment: It's not clear what the final formula means - it is missing a parenthesis. It would also be useful if you showed some work, not just your answer.

Comment: Definitely not. You should complete the square. That is:

$$x^2-x+1 = x^2 -\frac{1}{2}2 x +1 = x^2 -\frac{1}{2}x + \frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{4}+1$$

Comment: You just enounced (tried to enounce) a formula... What now? I.e., *what's the question*?

Answer (score 1):

$$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-x-1}}dx=\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{(x-\frac{1}{2})^2-\frac{5}{4}}}dx$$

$$x-0.5=\frac{\sqrt 5}{2}\cosh t$$

$$I=\int \frac{\sinh t}{\sqrt{\cosh^2 t-1}}dt=t$$

$$I=\cosh^{-1}(\frac{2}{\sqrt 5}(x-0.5))$$

where is $\cosh^{-1} t$ is [inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function#Inverse_functions_as_logarithms) of $\cosh t$

---

let

$$x=\cosh y \Rightarrow x=\frac{e^y+e^{-y}}{2}$$

$$e^{2y}-2xe^y+1=0$$

by quadratic formula

$$e^y=x+\sqrt{x^2-1}$$

so

$$y=\operatorname{arccosh} x=\log(x+\sqrt{x^2-1})$$

$$$$